# Cannot coerce string to boolean in mule4

Tags: string, compiler-errors, boolean, mule4, coerce

Getting cannot coerce string to boolean error when running the below expression in mule4

```
vars.userId != null and (vars.page != null and vars.page contains ('Redeem')) or (vars.actionName != null and vars.actionName contains ('Redeem'))
```

This is the error:

```
org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "Cannot coerce String (ungatedRedeem) to Boolean
Trace:
  at contains (Unknown)
  at main (line: 1, column: 58)" evaluating expression: "vars.userId != null and (vars.page != null and vars.page contains ('Redeem')) or (vars.actionName != null and vars.actionName contains ('Redeem'))".
```

Note: The expression is returning expected output when evaluated separately. Example: when evaluated this expression `vars.actionName != null and vars.actionName contains ('Redeem')` returns `true` but when added `vars.userId != null and (vars.page != null and vars.page contains ('Redeem')) or (vars.actionName != null and vars.actionName contains ('Redeem'))` it starts throwing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Short Answer:

Wrap the contains call in its own Parentheses. `(vars.page != null) and (vars.page contains ('Redeem')`

##### Explaination

The issue that you are facing is because of the order of [precedence of different operator in DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-flow-control-precedence). If you go through the link you will notice that, in your expression `and` operator will execute before `contains`

Therefore the expression `vars.page != null and vars.page contains ('Redeem')` **could**** throw an error because DataWeave interpret this:

1. DW first checks if `vars.page != null`. Lets say it is not so this result to `true`.
2. Then it tries to do `(vars.page != null and vars.page)` or `true and vars.page`. I believe the `vars.page` is a String, therefore you are seeing that error because DW is trying to convert String to Boolean.

The resolution is simple. Just wrap the contains call in its own Parentheses. `(vars.page != null) and (vars.page contains ('Redeem')`

****about that could** *(also why the other expression is working separately)*. The reason why the expression `vars.actionName != null and vars.actionName contains ('Redeem')` worked on its own is because of the logical `and` and `or` operators short-circuit, meaning they don't evaluate the remaining parts if they don't have to. So if the first expression `vars.actionName != null` evaluates to false, then checking the rest of the conditions is not necessary because the result will always be false, so the DW skips the evaluation of the remaining expression. Therefore, depending on the value of `actionName` your expression **could** fail.
You can read more about short circuiting here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Alternatively, you can switch to  prefix notation to avoid Parentheses. `vars.page != null and contains(vars.page, 'Redeem')`, depends on your preference

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parenthesis to make precedence explicit. It is considering one of the variable as the `and` argument before evaluating contains().

`(vars.actionName != null and (vars.actionName contains ('Redeem')))`

Same for `vars.page contains ('Redeem')`. Change it to `(vars.page contains ('Redeem'))`.